# mysql: SOURCE error 2?

Tags: mysql

When I tried to source for a particular .sql file, namely `'metropolises.sql'` that I created and saved previously from a database, the following error is displayed:

> Failed to open file 'metropolises.sql', error: 2

Any idea what went wrong?

Comment: What does it mean to "try to source for a particuar .sql file"?

Comment: I created a table in a database. Now, in order to get the data created, I typed 

SOURCE metropolises.sql;

into the terminal, however the error message as described above showed up. Pretty sure there's no error in the table created.

Answer (score 111):

Assuming you mean that you are trying to use [the `source` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html) in order to execute SQL statements from a text file, the error number given appears to be passed through from the POSIX layer.

Therefore, using [this resource](http://www.barricane.com/c-error-codes-include-errno), we can deduce that the error value of 2 means "no such file or directory".

**In short, you got the path wrong.**

Try providing an *absolute path*, as it's not clear what the *current working directory* will be in the context of your MySQL server. You may be assuming that it's the working directory of your shell, but it's not obvious that we should expect this to be true.

Comment: Thanks. I know this is stupid, but how to find the file I created under within a database?

Comment: Provide an absolute path. The full path. Including directory.

Comment: As an added note, do not put the full path in quotes.  `SOURCE "/var/test.sql";` will fail with error code 2, while `SOURCE /var/test.sql` will work (assuming test.sql exists at that location).

Comment: yup, just a simple misspelling of the sql file triggered mine

Comment: Why are they not just throwing **"no such file or directory"** instead of a cryptic error code number ..???

Comment: @Black: You'd have to ask them!

Answer (score 42):

Just use the **absolute path** of the file and then, instead of using backslashes, use **forward** slashes.

**Example:**

with **backslashes** : source C:\folder1\metropolises.sql
with **forward slashes** : source C:/folder1/metropolises.sql

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to store the path in a global or local variable (e.g @PATH_TO_THE_FILE) and use the source command as in "source @PATH_TO_THE_FILE" (this does not work)? Thanks.

Comment: didn't work for me. Shows same error despite modifying to absolute path with forward slashes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27):

> ## IF YOU ARE USING MYSQL INSIDE DOCKER

Note that if you are running MySQL inside docker then you must first copy the dump into your MySQL docker environment. To do that follow the steps below

1. First, check and copy the container ID for your MySQL docker by:

   `sudo docker ps`
2. Copy the SQL dump file into your container using:

   `sudo docker cp  /path/to/sql/file.sql MysqlDockerID:/`

   This will copy the dump file into the docker root folder if you want to copy the file inside any other directory/path inside docker replace the '/' after  'MysqlDockerID:' with the path you want appropriate one.
3. Now to interact with MySQL inside a running container run the following command:

   `sudo docker exec -it MysqlDockerID bin/bash`
4. Now connect to the MySQL using the terminal by:

   `mysql -u yourUserName -p`

   This will now ask you for the password. Enter the correct password to proceed.
5. List the databases available by:

   `show Databases;`

   This will list out the available databases
6. Assuming your database name where you want to import dump to is 'MyDatabase'. Switch to that using:

   `use MyDatabase`
7. Now you can import the file by typing:

   `source file.sql`

   Remember the above command works if you have copied your file into your root folder (using step 2). If you have copied it to any other path make sure you use that same path instead

Comment: this is a life saver. by the way, one thing to note, for step 2, you have to explicitly create a folder inside `/` if you want a different folder other than the root path. not doing so will result to an error that looks something like `Error: No such container:path: <container_id>:\<folder_name>`

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Thanks for sharing this specific case.

Comment: man... i love you!

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH! REALLY A LIFE SAVER :D

Answer (score 15):

Related issue I had getting error 2 running source command: filename must not be in quotes even if it contains spaces in name or path to file.

Comment: One tends to think that with spaces in the path quotes are necessary. What a headache!

Answer (score 14):

It's probably the file path to your file. If you don't know the exact location of the file you want to use, try to find your file in Finder, then drag the file into Terminal window

```
mysql> SOURCE dragfilePathHere
```

Comment: BRO, YOU'RE A LIFE SAVER!
My problem was absolutely unclear, turned out my file was named "file.sql.sql", but that didn't show in the GUI, only appeared when I dragged and dropped it onto the cmd

Answer (score 5):

I first reach to the file

```
c:\windows>cd c:\akura\Db Scripts

c:\akura\Db Scripts>mysql -u root -p root

mysql>\. EXECUTER_NEW_USER.sql

here EXECUTER_NEW_USER.sql my file name
```

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same error on Windows.
I solved it with (after on cmd: mysql -u root):

```
mysql> SOURCE C:/users/xxx/xxxx/metropolises.sql;
```

Be sure you type the right file path

Answer (score 3):

On my windows 8.1, and mysql 5.7.9 MySQL Community Server (GPL), 
I had to remove the `;` after the file path.

This failed: source `E:/jokoni/db/Banking/createTables.sql;`

This Worked: source `E:/jokoni/db/Banking/createTables.sql`
(without termination, and forward slashes instead of windows' backslashes in path)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vagrant ensure that the file is on the server and then use the path to the file. e.g if the file is stored in the public folder you will have

```
sql> source /var/www/public/xxx.sql
```

Where xxx is the name of the file

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in mysql command line using this query:

```
source `db.sql`;
```

I changed the above to the following to make it work:

```
source db.sql;
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Mac, this is the only solution worked for me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45530305/5414448

```
1 - Download the .sql file and remember it's location.

2 - Open your mysql from command prompt or terminal.

3 - Create a database with the same name as that of the database present in the .sql file (create database your_database_name)

4 - Now exit out from the mysql command line client

5 - Now try and execute this command =>

mysql -u your_username -p your_database_name < your_sql_file_with_complete_location

example -  mysql -u root -p trial < /home/abc/Desktop/trial.sql

here my .sql file is named trial and is present in the desktop, the database is also name trial

6 - You should now have your sql file imported to the corresponding mysql database.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and it turns out if you are using wamp server to run mysql, you have to use the file path within the wamp64 folder. So when the absolute path is: `C:/wamp64/www/foldername/filename.sql`
The path you have to use is:
`www/foldername/filename.sql`

Answer (score 0):

May be the file name or path you are used may be incorrect

In my system i created file abcd.sql at c:\

and used command `mysql> source c:\abcd.sql`  Then i got result

Comment: Actually, I'm doing it on ssh. How to view the directories of the files created on a particular database?

Comment: @PengHuiHow - do you know the actual path of that file?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Debian 8 (Jessie) Linux, try to `cd` into the directory of the `'metropolises.sql'`. Run `mysql` and execute `SOURCE ./metropolises.sql;`

Basically, try the *relative path*. I tried this and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running dockerized MySQL container such as ones from this official Docker Image registry: https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/ You may encounter [this issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/166) as well.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because the file was located on a shared drive and it could not access, for some reason, to that path.
I cut the file and put it on my local drive in a path without spaces and it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got  the same error when i used the command source and gave the sql file path by drag n dropping it.

Then I just had to remove those single quotes which appeared by default with drag and drop, a space before file extension and it worked.

soln:

source /home/xyz/file .sql ;(path and a space before file extension)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac users, you can give the path as,

```
source /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Desktop/metropolises.sql;
```

*I have assumed that the file you need to `source` is in your `desktop` and the file name is `metropolises.sql`

---

If you type,

```
source metropolises.sql
```

then the file will be look in the default location,

```
/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/metropolises.sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was file permissions in Windows. Just give full control in the file to all users and it will work. After the import, get the permissions back to what it was before.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem on my Mac because one of the folder (directory) names in the path had a space in the name. BTW, the space was escaped by a \, but that was not understood by mySQL

Answer (score 0):

solution - 1) Make sure you're in the `root` folder of your app. eg app/db/schema.sql.

solution - 2) open/reveal the folder on your window and drag`&&`drop in the command line next to keywork `source` (*space*) filesource. eg source User/myMAC/app/db/schema.sql

Answer (score 0):

I get into this problem in my Xubuntu desktop. I fixed it by renaming all my files and folders so there is no space in the file path.

Answer (score 0):

Passing the full path does not error, but if the folders have MySQL spaces it does not recognize the .sql file.
I have MySQL 8.0.21 on OS UNIX.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error on Windows. I solved it running the code on MySQL command line

```
source c:\Users\xx\Downloads\data_file.sql
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Remove spaces in the folder names of the path, It worked for my mac path.

> (Eg: change the folder name MySQL Server 5.1 to MySQLServer5.1)

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same message when I try from the MySQL console. However, when I open the command prompt and do the same steps it works.

```
C:\Users\SubhenduD>cd ../
C:\Users>cd ../
C:\>cd \xampp\mysql\bin

C:\xampp\mysql\bin>mysql -u -root

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 68
Server version: 5.6.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. 
Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.


mysql> use balticktravels;

mysql> source balticktravels.sql;
```