# can't load .sql file into mysql mac

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite

I have mysql running, I've switched to my database using:

`use myDb;`

now I'm trying to run a sql script located on my desktop using the following:

`source /Users/abdul/Desktop/mySql.sql;`

but I keep getting this error:

> Failed to open file '/Users/abdul/Desktop/mySql.sql;', error: 2

not sure what I'm doing wrong, I've been researching and everything says to do it the way I did it.

Comment: [Error 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684063/mysql-source-error-2) is "No such file or directory."  Check your spelling, capitalization, and then verify that the account running mysqld has access to the file in question.  Try putting the file in your Public or Shared folder, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Error 2` stands for "No such file or directory". Try checking for any spelling errors in the file. Also make sure `MySQL` has access to the file in that location.