# How to import database from a large SQL file of hundreds MBs to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import, backup

I have one SQL file which contains database and is 450+ MB. I tried phpMyAdmin, however phpMyAdmin does not support the import of such large files.

Can anyone suggest way or command to import it through command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this.

Here's one way:

1. Login to mysql (e.g. `mysql -u root -p`)
2. `Create database testimport_db;`
3. `use testimport_db;`
4. `source pathname_of_your_sql_file/your_sql_filename.sql`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Other ways:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html

**Note:** If you get the path of your sql fle wrong. Then use absolute path instead. Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684063/mysql-source-error-2)

**EDIT:**

Another way:

`mysql -uroot -p[your_password] database_name < sql file`

If you want to run this as background process in **LINUX** then put an `&` at the end like below:

`mysql -uroot -p[your_password] database_name < sql file &`

Comment: Please leave any message if you find any trouble. Just put @Subrata Dey Pappu after your message.

Comment: Sounds great! @The_Amol

Answer (score 0):

1. Using MySql Load Data 
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html
2. Using MySql Import
   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html

Comment: Thanks Ramachandran for quick reply. but i checked these links.. these are for text files with data.. but not for sql file with quries for creating and inserting data..