# MySQL and SQL Scripts

Tags: mysql, database

So I'm learning MySQL.  So far, its been a great thing to learn and I haven't had any issues.  However, when it comes to creating and running a SQL script, I've found myself very stuck.

I've created a script which shows the current databases, then creates a new database and finally shows the databases again.  Originally, my problem looked exactly like this one: [mysql: SOURCE error 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684063/mysql-source-error-2).  I followed the advice by applying forward slashes instead of back slashes.  This worked in the sense that I got no errors, but nothing happened; no output at all..?

The script (s1_create-db.sql) is:

```
#Reveal existing databases

SHOW DATABASES;

/*Create a new database called "my_DB"
only if a database with that name does not exist */

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS my_DB;

#Reveal databases

SHOW DATABASES;
```

Originally I ran the script with:

```
SOURCE C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\s1_create-db
```

which gave me:

```
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\s1_create-db',error: 2
```

I then ran:

```
SOURCE C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/s1_create-db.sql
```

which gave me nothing.  I checked to see if the new DB had been created, but it hadn't.

Any advice is highly appreciated!!!!

Comment: Obviously the first error is because you left out  the `.sql` at the end.  Did the last command give any output at all?

Comment: Nothing at all.  It just went to the prompt mysql>

Comment: You could try putting a deliberate error in your script, just to check it is actually being run.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  So I tried to add an error into t he script.  First thing I noticed was that the script file is 0kb in size.  This implies there's nothing in it at all  I guess...?  Secondly, on opening the file, I was taken to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, which surprised me a bit.... The connection to the database engine failed.  I now have more problems than I started with; I'm obviously out of depth now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note to anyone who may come across this question.  I found out how to do it; give up on Windows and go back to Linux.  I'm still not sure what went on/wrong, but Linux gave me what I needed.  Thanks to anyone who looked at the question and had a think.