# failed to open file in mysql database

Tags: mysql

i downloaded employees database from github that recommend mysql in its website but it has error in importing . how can i fix it?
i dont think it is corrupt database.the error is

```
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_salaries1.dump', error: 2
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_salaries2.dump', error: 2
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'load_salaries3.dump', error: 2
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'show_elapsed.sql', error: 2
```

and my refrence https://dev.mysql.com/doc/employee/en/employees-installation.html
and also it is added to my databases but with these errors

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem and here is the solution.

**Root Cause**

The path for the dump files in the `employees.sql` script is not absolute or relative.

If you open the `employees.sql` script with an IDE (say, Visual Studio Code), you would find the below sql commands at the end of it.

> SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
>
> source load_salaries1.dump ;
>
> source load_salaries2.dump ;
>
> source load_salaries3.dump ;
>
> source show_elapsed.sql ;

**Solution**

Simply add the absolute path of the files and rerun the script file. Like below:

> SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
>
> source C:/Users/abc/Downloads/test_db-master/load_salaries1.dump ;
>
> source C:/Users/abc/Downloads/test_db-master/load_salaries2.dump ;
>
> source C:/Users/abc/Downloads/test_db-master/load_salaries3.dump ;
>
> source C:/Users/abc/Downloads/test_db-master/show_elapsed.sql ;

*Note - You may have to do it for other such dump files as well in the employees.sql script*

Answer (score 0):

Error 2 in MySQL means "File not found." Make sure that you are in the right directory and you put quotation marks ("") around directory names that has a space.

Comment: this is my command source C:/Users/Sina/Downloads/Compressed/test_db-master/test_db-master/employees.sql

Comment: try the directory `C:/Users/Sina/Downloads/Compressed/test_db-master/test_db-ma‌​ster` then run the `mysql -t < employees.sql` command

Comment: it says problem with syntax

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that "File not Found". Double check your filename & file directory and then try again.

Comment: So how it is added to my databases if the directory isnt valid but so with error

Comment: source C:/Users/Sina/Downloads/Compressed/test_db-master/test_db-master/employees.sql

Comment: keep this "employees.sql" on your htdocs folder (if you use xampp) or www folder (for Wamp server). You can't keep the file outside of the server. Try

Answer (score 0):

I used the following steps to import an sql file to my mysql application in ubuntu

1 - Download the .sql file and remember it's location.

2 - Open your mysql from command prompt or terminal.

3 - Create a database with the same name as that of the database present in the .sql file (create database your_database_name)

4 - Now exit out from the mysql command line client

5 - Now try and execute this command =>

`mysql -u your_username -p your_database_name < your_sql_file_with_complete_location`

example - 
`mysql -u root -p trial < /home/abc/Desktop/trial.sql`

here my .sql file is named trial and is present in the desktop, the database is also name trial

6 - You should now have your sql file imported to the corresponding mysql database.