# Laradock mysql import sql file... failed to open file

Tags: mysql, path, laradock

I am using Laradock on Mac and I am trying to import a large sql file into a new database.  Source returns an error 2 failed to open file, whatever path I use...

What is the correct path to my file?

/Users/paul/Sites/laradock (path to laradock)

/Users/paul/Sites/travelearn (path to laravel project)

/Users/paul/Downloads/TraveLearn.sql (path to sql file)

```
 mysql> SOURCE /Users/paul/Downloads/TraveLearn.sql
 ERROR: 
 Failed to open file '/Users/paul/Downloads/TraveLearn.sql', error: 2
 mysql> SOURCE Users/paul/Downloads/TraveLearn.sql
 ERROR: 
 Failed to open file 'Users/paul/Downloads/TraveLearn.sql', error: 2
```

Comment: You need to change the rights of the file

Comment: either make a volume from your local Mac to your container or do a `docker exec` and somehow execute that `source` command with docker exec, mysql, etc, from your Mac command line

Comment: Thank you @UnderDog... I found the solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684063/mysql-source-error-2